# Is “hold-your-nose (or close –your-eyes) - and-do sth” an English idiom or just a coinage for one-off use?

Tags: expressions

I found a phrase, “a hold-your-nose-and-roll-the-camera” in the following statement of NPR’s article (April 2) titled “From pets to plates: Why more people rre eating guinea pigs?”
http://www.npr.org/blogs/thesalt/2013/03/12/174105739/from-pets-to-plates-why-more-people-are-eating-guinea-pigs?ft=3&f=111787346&sc=nl&cc=es-20130407

> “While guinea pig may be attaining star status as
>   **a hold-your-nose-and-roll-the-camera bizarre food**, whether an animal
>   so favored as a pet in the United States will become a mainstream
>   piece of protein is, perhaps, doubtful.”

Is the phrase, “hold one’s nose and do sth. (roll the camera XXX)” that seems convenient to apply to any other variations e.g., “Close your eyes and eat the guinea pig” an idiom, or a set pattern of phrase, or just a one-off coinage for this article?

Comment: This (as well as being a nonce-word) is either an adverb applying to *bizarre* or an adjective applying to *food*, so you may want to recast the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hold your nose and X* is a well-understood English expression, where X is some activity which is at once necessary and repugnant. For example, two of the top three related searches Google suggests for me are

> hold your nose and vote for obama
>
> hold your nose and vote for romney

*Close your eyes and X* and *look away and X* have similar meanings.

In this case, however, *hold-your-nose-and-roll-the-camera bizarre food* is a one-off phrase recalling television competitions where contestants must eat some kind of food they consider disgusting. It is *hold-your-nose* food because it is repulsive but must be consumed to win the competition, and *roll-the-camera* food because it is only being consumed for the sake of TV audiences.

Comment: argh, beat me to it.  +1 for you.  :-)

Comment: In the UK *Close your eyes and think of England* would be the common phraseology

Comment: @Kyudos. What does 'Close your eyes and think of England' mean?

Comment: @Kyudos:  It means "When faced with an unpleasant task, think of something pleasant."  In this case--assuming you are an Anglophile, think of your beloved England!  To change the metaphor from sight to taste, from the film "The Sound of Music" comes the following:  "A spoonful of sugar helps the medicine  go down, in the most delightful way."  Here, England is the pleasing sugar, and taking the medicine is the unpleasant task.  Thinking of, or tasting, something pleasant can take one's mind off something unpleasant.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @Kyudos: I'm more familiar with it as ["Lie back and think of England"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Lie+back+and+think+of+England%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which more strongly implies the "unpleasant task" is that facing a woman obliged to satisfy a man's unwanted sexual demands.

Comment: @rhetrician. I understood. We don’t have the eqivalent idom to ‘Close your eyes and think of England,’ though it sounds like we don’t love our own country as much as you do.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: You are correct, that, I think, was the original insinuation, but I think it also gets applied to other "unpleasant tasks" - perhaps in a jocular way though.